# Importing certificate from site using Ansible java_cert

Tags: ansible, certificate, trusted-sites, cacerts

I am pondering the use of the Ansible [java_cert](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/java_cert_module.html) module to import certificate from trusted sites.

Using bash this can be accomplished using the following

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect sh.1.1.1.3.nip.io:443 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > /tmp/nipio.pem
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8u192/jre/bin/keytool -importcert -noprompt -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8u192/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -alias 'nipio' -file /tmp/nipio.pem
```

Easy enough. When I check, the certificate is in the keystore

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8u192/jre/bin/keytool -list -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8u192/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit | grep nipio
```

Per my understanding of Ansible [java_cert](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/java_cert_module.html) the following Ansible YAML code should be used to achieve the same

```
- java_cert:
    cert_alias: nipio
    cert_url: sh.1.1.1.3.nip.io
    cert_port: 443
    keystore_path: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8u192/jre/lib/security/cacerts
    keystore_pass: changeit
    executable: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8u192/jre/bin/keytool
    state: present
```

Each time I run Ansible my task is "changed" which suggest that Ansible is updating the keystore. But the certificat will not be "present" but missing.

```
TASK [cacerts : Import trusted sites] ****************************
changed: [bitbucket] => (item={u'url': u'sh.1.1.1.3.nip.io', u'port': 443, u'name': u'nipio'})
```

There is a return value with the command which suggests that the command is run without anything to import?

```
cmd': u\"/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8u192/jre/bin/keytool -importcert -noprompt -keystore '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8u192/jre/lib/security/cacerts' -storepass '********' -alias 'nipio' \"
```

Is this a known issue with `java_cert`? How it this supposed to work?